Question about Exercise 6.4 in *Vector Analysis* by Klaus Jänich
I'm working on a problem from Klaus Jänich's book "Vector Analysis" and would appreciate some help with understanding the author's hint.
Exercise 6.4:
Prove that every compact manifold $ M $ without boundary on which there exists a fixed-point-free differentiable involution $ \tau $ is "null-bordant"; that is, it bounds a compact manifold.
Author's Hint:
The not so obvious idea is (more or less) to connect each $ x $ and $ \tau(x) $ by a line segment, so as to construct a compact manifold $ W $ with $ \partial W = M $. But how can this be carried out technically? One can, for instance, start with the manifold (without boundary) $ M \times \mathbb{R} $ and then take a quotient (also without boundary) $ (M \times \mathbb{R}) / \sim$ under a suitable free involution (I think he means free of fixed points) . This can be done in such a way that the desired $ W $ appears as a submanifold-with-boundary $ f^{-1}((-\infty, c)] $ in the quotient.
Clarification Request:

Understanding the Hint:: Could you explain in more detail how to interpret the hint provided for Exercise $6.4$? Specifically, what is the equivalence relation to put on $M \times \mathbb{R}$ could it be the one induced by the map $$ (x, t) \to (\tau (x), t) \ ? $$ Finally, what is meant by line segment in an abstract manifold? Did the author forget to state the connectedness hypothesis?


Start with the simplest case where $M = {0, 1}$ is just two points with the involution interchanging the two points. We know that $M$ is the boundary of an interval which you can think of as a line segment, say $[0, 1]$ joining the two points. This is what the author means by adding a line segment: it is a line segment exterior to the manifold.
To get line segments in general, we need to look at the cylinder $M\times[0, 1]$ over $M$. If I want the line segment to go from $x$ to $\tau(x)$, then the obvious thing to do is to quotient the boundary of this cylinder by something like $(x, 0)\sim (\tau(x), 1)$ - but this doesn't work! It gets rid of all boundary (and might not even give something smooth/differentiable).
To ensure smoothness, identify the neighbourhoods via $(x, t)\sim(\tau(x), 1-t)$. This is an involution without fixed points. Intuitively, for a fixed $x, (x, t)$ is a path starting from $x$ and $(\tau(x), t)$ is a path starting from $\tau(x)$ and these two should represent the same line segment in different orientations. I will leave you to verify that $(M\times[0, 1])/\sim$ is the manifold you are after.

Couple of other things to mention. Quotienting by $(x, t)\sim(\tau(x), t)$ simply gives a cylinder over $M/\tau$. To use $M\times\mathbb{R}$, you can use the $(x, t)\sim(\tau(x), -t)$ equivalence relation and then choose an $f$ carefully so that $f^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ is compact (hint:

 squaring the $t$ coordinate works)

The manifold $W$ constructed above is the mapping cylinder for the projection $M\to M/\tau$ and because this is a two-to-one map, near $M/\tau$ two half spaces are joined to create something without boundary, so the boundary is just $M$. The line segment the author mentions in the hint goes from $x\in M$ down to $[x]\in M/\tau$ and then back up to $\tau(x)$.

thanks for the answer, but I have further question. You said that you can't quotient $M \times \mathbb{R},$ but what if chose a slightly different equivalence relation? For example I could think of identifying all the couples $(x,t), (x,t+k)$ where $k$ is an integer or something like that. I haven't verified it yet, but I think you know what mean: slightly change the equivalence relation so that $M \times [0,1]$ is the actual fundamental domain.

@MatteoAldovardi I have edited the answer. Note that translation is not an involution (and identifies $0, 1$).
